# Hg cloning done with new repositories does not clone the files?

Tags: mercurial

I am new to hg mercuriall
here is what I did

```
:~$ hg init repo1  
:~$ cd repo1/  
:~/repo1$ echo Hello World > file1  
:~/repo1$ cd   
:~$ hg clone repo1 repo2
```

After this I expect the file 1 to be appeared at repo2 but it shows no files with such names in repo2.where am I going wrong
am I expecting correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two additional steps after creating file1:

```
hg add file1
hg commit -m "A message describing what file1 is for"
```

Just creating a file does not add it to the repository.

You may also find this helpful: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your work sequence you add the `file1` to your newly-created repository. A repository does not automatically track every file or change made therein. You have to explicitly tell the repo to track the changes made to it.

The sequence usually looks like

```
:~$ hg init repo1
:~$ cd repo1/
:~/repo1$ echo Hello World > file1
:~/repo1$ hg add file1
:~/repo1$ hg commit -m "Add: file1"
:~/repo1$ cd
:~$ hg clone repo1 repo2
```